# Listening on Serial Port already in use by another application

Tags: c#

I am stuck with below mentioned problem.

1. Application 1(c#) on machine is communicating with device1 over physical serial port (RS232).Application 1 sends the command and device 1 sends the response over serial port.
   2.I want to read the response from device in another application2 (in c#) at the same time when application 1 is listening on serial port.

Application 1 is already implemented in c# and i need to create application 2 in c#.

Please let me know how I can read the response from device in application 2 over same serial port.

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: You can't open the same com port twice. The only thing I can think about is that your first application share the data read with your second app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pikoh. but i am very new to this area.Can you please help me to know the details or mechanism by which  my first application can share the data with application 2.

Comment: Try to make virtual COM port and connect first app to this and spy application by pass data from port to virtual port.

Comment: How does serial port sniffing tools (Docklight or device monitoring studio) monitors the data at the same comport which is already in use?